# Higher-order Schrödinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation

Starting from this equation:
$$
\mathbf {\hat H} \Psi = E\Psi
$$
We have:
$$
E= \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2}
$$
Performing a Taylor approximation:
$$
E \approx mc^2 + \frac{p^2}{2m} - \frac{p^4}{8 m^3 c^2} + \mathcal O(p^6)
$$
$$
\hat p = -i\hbar\nabla
$$
$$
\mathbf{\hat H} = mc^2 - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 - \frac{\hbar^4}{8 m^3 c^2}\nabla^4 + V(\mathbf r)
$$
then,
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \Psi - \frac{\hbar^4}{8 m^3 c^2}\nabla^4\Psi + V(\mathbf r)\Psi = (E - mc^2)\Psi
$$
where $\nabla^4$ is the [biharmonic operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation?oldformat=true). I've tried to solve this equation for a quadratic potential, with no angular dependence. But, damn, this equation is hard. Is there any known analytic solution to this equation? Is this line of reasoning right? Is this equation valid for describing semi-classical particles?

Comment: Ah yes ... what Dirac cleverly avoided, but instead taking that bull by its horns! Interesting ...

Comment: Usually, the first relativistic correction to the kinetic energy is treated perturbatively (to first order), leading to one of the three corrections of the atomic spectrum known as fine structure. But I guess that you do not want a perturbative correction.

Comment: What do you take as $V$?

Comment: @my2cts $\frac{1}{2}\mu \omega^2 r^2$

Comment: As Christophe says, this is used perturbatively. The energy is not bounded from below, so you can't use it as the full Hamiltonian. You would at least need to add the $p^6$ term, but the whole point of using an expansion is to do something neglecting the higher order terms, so an exact solution for the approximate Hamiltonian is not really useful.

Comment: Not exactly the same but similar to your problem and I  think you will find [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-022-00541-5) interesting. It avoids the square root by using a continued fraction approach. This [article](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1976234) discusses your problem.